# What is the alternative for storing set in sharedPreference using only api 8 in android?

Tags: android, android-json

using Set in sharedpreference is API lv11;

i have a project need to parse to many types of nested items
and need to save it to sharedpreference using only string,
the xml items is very complicated to save as a normal string to
sharedpreference, if i use normal string it need to create
so many sharedpreference names and values,
My question is, is JSON is the alternative because its string is
like a list so that i can read easily the items in per category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using internal storage over SharedPreferences.

[Here is more information on internal storage.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `JSON` as a string and save it to the `SharedPreference` that is because `JSON` is faster , smaller and less verbose structure than `XML`.

Comment: the process will be parse from XML from site, then convert the XMLSTRING to JSON then create JSON like database type that has category to search easily something like that?